# What does the tagline of "The Kings of Summer" mean?

Tags: posters, the-kings-of-summer

On the posters for *The Kings of Summer* there is a slogan:

> Why live when you can rule?

What does this mean? Does it imply that they are being with the nature and ruling it instead of having to care about the world that we are in which is the busy world without nature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The synopsis of the movie -- [as quoted by **FilmoFilia**](http://www.filmofilia.com/the-kings-of-summer-trailer-143189/) -- makes it clear:

> THE KINGS OF SUMMER is a unique coming-of-age comedy about three
>   teenage friends [...] who, in **the ultimate act of independence**,
>   decide to spend their summer building a house in the woods and living
>   off the land. **Free from their parents’ rules**, their idyllic summer
>   quickly becomes a test of friendship as each boy learns to appreciate
>   the fact that family – whether it is the one you’re born into or the
>   one you create – is something you can’t run away from.

This [dialogue excerpt](http://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/movie_script.php?movie=the-kings-of-summer) refers to the same theme:

> This is the site of our new house, man.
>
> What, like a tree house?
>
> No, like a real house. I'm moving out. We're moving out.
>
> What the hell are you talking about? **My mom won't let me walk around
>   the house without socks on. She's definitely not going to let us live
>   out here in the woods.**
>
> No one will find us out here, Patrick. **This house, this land, it's
>   ours! We make the rules, you know? Like men!**

Instead of "just living" and having to follow their parents' rules, they leave home and are "kings of their own domain".

Comment: It's also probably a play on words - rule as a king but also 'rule', as in 'be awesome'.

Comment: Thank you . I guess i'm just  getting stuck in the meaning of "live" in the tagline . They should "rule" instead of " live " .  But really , how can you not live ?